# Python user input and printing out

Tags: python

```
chargePerDay = 30.0
feeEachMile = 0.5
fuelPerGallon = 1.5

print("How many users are there?")
numberOfUsers = input()

for i in range(numberOfUsers):
    print('For user ' + i)

    print("Number of days")
    numberOfDays = input()

    print("Number of miles")
    numberOfMiles = input()

    totalRentalFee = (chargePerDay * float(numberOfDays)) + (feeEachMile * float(numberOfMiles))
    print('Hi user ' + i + ' Your total rental fee is ' + str(totalRentalFee))
```

When I run it it is printing 
for i in range(numberOfUsers):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

What is wrong with this?? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` returns a string. `range` wants an integer.

Change `range(numberOfUsers)` to `range(int(numberOfUsers))`

The next error is in the following lines when you try to concatenate strings with the integer `i`. Use `str(i)` in the calls to `print`.

Answer (score 3):

You're input is coming in as a string, you need to convert it to an integer:

```
numberOfUsers = int(input())
# ... rest of code
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast to `int`.

```
numberOfUsers = int(input())
```

Python 2's `input()` evaluates automatically, whereas Python 3 got rid of 2's `input()` and replaced it with the equivalent of `raw_input()` which takes input as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using integer data objects instead of strings. To convert them, use this code:

```
chargePerDay = 30.0
feeEachMile = 0.5
fuelPerGallon = 1.5

print("How many users are there?")
numberOfUsers = input()

for i in range(numberOfUsers):
    print('For user ' + str(i))

    print("Number of days")
    numberOfDays = input()

    print("Number of miles")
    numberOfMiles = input()

    totalRentalFee = (chargePerDay * float(numberOfDays)) + (feeEachMile * float(numberOfMiles))
    print('Hi user ' + str(i) + ' Your total rental fee is ' +     str(totalRentalFee))
```